# How to add a bottom curve in a div - CSS?

Tags: html, css

Following is my code in which I am unable to create a bottom curve but increasing the border-top-left-radius/border-top-right-radius is not able to create a bump as shown in fig. Let me know how can I handle this using CSS only.

**Code:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.rect {
  width: 334.5px;
  height: 223px;
  background: #34EFEE;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 223px;
}
.rect:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 334.5px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect">
    <h3>334.5 X 223</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected Output -

[image: Expected Output]

**PLNKR** -- http://plnkr.co/edit/7oTCHyn8PFABri0KHSrH?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo element to create shape and add large `box-shadow` for blue background.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px #00A2E8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: You're the only person who thought to make the after transparent (something I'd have missed too), so you get an upvote from me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code change height  and border-top-left-radius like

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.rect {
  width: 334.5px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #34EFEE;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 223px;
}
.rect:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 334.5px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 80%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect">
    <h3>334.5 X 223</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the code, but if you notice that the bump in you snippet is not in the middle but to the left.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.rect {
  width: 334.5px;
  height: 223px;
  background: #34EFEE;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 223px;
}
.rect:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #fff;
  left: -11px;
  bottom: -270px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect">
    <h3>334.5 X 223</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can edit it by playing with borders and other stuff

Comment: <style type="text/css">
  .container { position: relative; }
  .rect { width: 334.5px; height: 223px; background: #34EFEE; text-align: center; line-height: 223px; }
  .rect:after { content: ''; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 260px; height:260px; transform:rotate(-44deg) skew(57deg, 57deg); background-color:#fff; left:30px; bottom:-173px; border-radius:30px;  }  
 </style>

Answer (score 0):

May as well through in another answer, this is not one I'd expect you to use but is one that uses clip path.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;  
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: #00A2E8;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 96% 99%, 92% 97%, 88% 95%, 84% 93%, 80% 91%, 76% 89%, 72% 87%, 68% 85%, 64% 83%, 60% 81%, 56% 79%, 52% 78%, 50% 78%, 48% 78%, 44% 79%, 40% 81%, 36% 83%, 32% 85%, 28% 87%, 24% 89%, 20% 91%, 16% 93%, 12% 95%, 08% 97%, 04% 99%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 96% 99%, 92% 97%, 88% 95%, 84% 93%, 80% 91%, 76% 89%, 72% 87%, 68% 85%, 64% 83%, 60% 81%, 56% 79%, 52% 78%, 50% 78%, 48% 78%, 44% 79%, 40% 81%, 36% 83%, 32% 85%, 28% 87%, 24% 89%, 20% 91%, 16% 93%, 12% 95%, 08% 97%, 04% 99%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```